# What is the default background color of UITableViewCell in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios13

What is the default background `UIColor` of `UITableViewCell`? I need a constant `UIColor` object rather than RGB as I wish to implement dark mode in iOS 13. (I couldn't find any matching color such as `[UIColor systemBackgroundColor]`).

I placed a breakpoint at `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and printed `cell.backgroundColor`. This is what I got:

```
<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000bf2c00; name = tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor>
```

It seems like a private class with no public equivalent. Any suggestions how to target this?

Comment: Those wanting to peek at system color values, check this blog https://noahgilmore.com/blog/dark-mode-uicolor-compatibility

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Cells in a plain styled table view use `UIColor.systemBackground[Color]` for their background, `UIColor.label[Color]` for the title text, and `UIColor.secondaryLabel[Color]` for the subtitle text.

For a grouped style table view, the cell background uses `UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground[Color]` and the table view background uses `UIColor.systemGroupedBackground[Color]`.

All of these adapt to light/dark mode.

Below is a helpful UIColor extension that allows you to print the light and dark description of any color.

```
extension UIColor {
    var lightDarkDescription: String {
        let lightTraits = UITraitCollection.init(userInterfaceStyle: .light)
        let darkTraits = UITraitCollection.init(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
        let lightColor = self.resolvedColor(with: lightTraits)
        let darkColor = self.resolvedColor(with: darkTraits)
        if lightColor == darkColor {
            return self.description
        } else {
            return "\(self), light: \(lightColor), dark: \(darkColor)"
        }
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground.lightDarkDescription)
print(UIColor.secondaryLabel.lightDarkDescription)
print(UIColor.green.lightDarkDescription)
```

Output:

> <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x6000005a5d80; name = secondarySystemGroupedBackgroundColor>, light: UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1, dark: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.109804 0.109804 0.117647 1
>   <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x6000005a5f00; name = secondaryLabelColor>, light: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.235294 0.235294 0.262745 0.6, dark: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.921569 0.921569 0.960784 0.6
>   UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1

If anyone wants to play with all of the colors, see my [SystemColors](https://github.com/rmaddy/SystemColors) demo app on GitHub.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for helping out! May I ask what is your reference? I searched endlessly for an answer and couldn't find anything useful... So out of curiosity, it will be interesting to realize the source of information.

Comment: Largely trial and error. Last month I wrote a simple table view app that has a row for every UIColor constant using that color as the row's background. This lets me see all of the colors in both light and dark mode. I then compared the colors I see in the Contacts and Settings apps with what I see in my test app. The tricky part is that many of the predefined colors are partially transparent.

Comment: @Joshua I added a link to the app I created to play with all of the colors.

Comment: Did anyone dig even deeper and found out where the name `tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor` in the OPs question comes from? Or is this just another helper color that switches between grouped and plain table views?

Comment: At least the `UIUserInterfaceLevel` of a trait collection seems to be taken into account when the `tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor` resolves its color. I get different cell background colors depended on having the table view in a root level view controller or a presented view controller.

Comment: same @Klaas but seemingly only on iPad. I just made a color asset with light = white, dark = the above RGB color and used that instead of the default everywhere

Comment: One caveat for the `UIColor.systemGroupedBackground`.  If the `UITableView.Style` is `.insetGrouped` and the tableView is layed out in a viewController that was presented with `presentationStyle = .pageSheet`, the darkMode color is different.

Comment: These only exist in iOS 13. Any idea how to get the system background color on systems running older iOS versions?

Comment: @Klaas `tableCellGroupedBackround` was removed starting from iOS 6. `systemGroupedBackground` was added in iOS 13. For several years the only way to get this colour was to hard code the RGB values.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert If you inspect a grouped UITableView (iOS 14) in Xcode 12.5 , it reports that cell is still using "tableCellGroupedBackgroundColor". The documentation is misleading; it says that that "groupTableViewBackgroundColor is now the same as systemGroupedBackgroundColor" when in fact, a grouped tableViewCell's background color actually uses secondarySystemGroupedBackground. Cheers.

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 13, to support dark mode, you can use `secondarySystemGroupedBackground` for the cell background.

The Swift code:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    cellBackgroundColor = .secondarySystemGroupedBackground
} else {
    cellBackgroundColor = .white
}
```

Correspondingly, for group table view background, you can use (primary) `systemGroupedBackground`.

The new semantic colors are for groups, containing other groups (primary -> secondary -> tertiary), and not limiting to table views. It makes perfect sense. I wrote about it [here](https://samwize.com/2019/11/26/supporting-dark-mode-in-ios-13/).